# How to Display a Dynamically generated Excel Workbook using ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Can someone provide the basic classes/web tool to display a dynamically generated excel workbook in a web page?  I have already written the needed code to create an Excel workbook.  I am looking for the advice:

1. Once the workbook html is created, how do I populate a part of the page with its contents?  That is, the user presses a compute button and can view the html workbook document in the same page once the workbook has been completed.
2. What is the code to download an excel workbook when the user presses a download button?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can create a tabs container and add a sheet/tab.
Every sheet will have an html table, you can use something like the datatables plugin if you are not willing to write a simple function to generate an html table.

2)Do you want to download the file by using pure front end code or  just request the file and the back end to do the whole job? If you want to do everything be done in the front end then you can use something like that https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx
or if you want to do everything  in the back end just sent the file with response.write or send the binary data and create an 'a' element with href and then destroy it or use something like that http://danml.com/download.html